# Neutral mob timings

Tags: league-of-legends

What are the spawn timers on the various mobs on League of Legends?

1. Initial spawn time
2. Re-spawn times
3. Variables (*i.e; If you kill the Blue
   Golem and left one of his minions,
   does it affect the Blue Golem's
   respawn time? Different mob spawning order on Twisted Treeline*)

**Summoners Rift (5v5)**

- Wolf Camp
- Golem Camp
- Wraith Camp
- Blue Golem Camp
- Red Golem Camp
- Dragon
- Nashor

**Twisted Treeline (3v3)**

- Mixed minor Camps (Golem, Wolf,
  Wraith)
- Red Golem
- Black Wraith Camp(s)
- Green Wolf Camp(s)
- Dragon

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**For Summoner's Rift (5v5)**

Baron Nashor - 15:00 initial, 7:00 respawn after death

Dragon - 2:30 initial, 6:00 respawn after death

Lizard/Golem - 1:55 initial, 5:00 respawn after entire camp death

Wolf camp - 1:40 initial, 1:00 respawn after entire camp death

Wraith camp - 1:40 initial, 0:50 respawn after entire camp death

Small golem camp - 1:40 initial, 1:00 respawn after entire camp death

**For Twisted Treeline (3v3)**

Ebonmaw (Dragon) Buff - 4:40 initial, 5:00 respawn

Grez (Lizard) Buff - 2:10 initial, 4:00 respawn

Ghast/Rabid Wolf Buff - 1:55 initial, 3:00 respawn after entire camp death

All small camps - 1:40 initial, 1:15 respawn after entire camp death

**Not sure if these values are 100% accurate for Twisted Treeline after the recent jungle remake. If anyone has specific info, feel free to comment/edit it in.**

Special Notes:

The values listed for the Ghast/Rabid Wolf and Lizard/Golem initial spawn are 1:55 officially in the wiki, however this appears to vary by about 1s and in practice they're actually a bit closer to 1:54 on the in-game clock

As indicated, a camp of neutrals will not respawn if even one mob is left alive in that particular camp. The timer to respawn will not start until the last mob is killed. For example, if I kill the Blue Golem at exactly 3:00 but leave the small casters alive, the Blue Golem will not respawn at 8:00, but rather, 5:00 after whenever those two casters are killed.

Also, unlike HoN / DotA, neutral mobs will still respawn if there is something obstructing their spawn point (e.g. a ward, an object like Shaco's JitB or a Nidalee trap, a player, etc.)

Comment: Nice answer @TheQ!

Answer (score 0):

There are some information here based on experimentation : http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=1190342